# Create a column such that - If `x` lies in top 150, its value is "Good". Else its value is "Bad"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

How do I create a binary column `performance` in `tbl` such that -

If `x` lies in top 150 (our of 243), value of performance is "Good"

Else, value of performance is "Bad"

```
tbl <- tibble(x = runif(n = 243, min = 0, max = 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly your question  this should work:

```
tbl %>%
    arrange(desc(x)) %>%
    mutate(performance = case_when(
            row_number() < 150 ~ "Good",
            TRUE ~ "Bad"))
```